# A web page interacting with two servers

Tags: websocket, comet

I have a web page consisting of a mixture of dynamic and static contents.

By **static**, I mean things like layout, labels, buttons, text fields, tables, etc. In other words, the visual components of the page.

By **dynamic**, I mean the values shown as labels and in the tables automatically update themselves via websockets connection. More specifically, this interaction with the server is handled by a Javascript library that implements websockets protocol.

A logical setup in this case would be to have two servers serve the page: one that returns all the static parts as above, and the other returns the changing values.

The question is, how exactly should I implement this setup/design? Is it purely done in the front-end code (e.g. HTML plus Javascript), or needs to be setup in both front and back-ends?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for, but here is one option for a modern web app:

**Single-web page app with backend connected over WebSocket**.

All the static content (HTML, CSS, JS, Imgs, ..) can be served from a plain old Web server, a CDN or even be packaged up into a ZIP as a Web widget.

All interaction with the backend is via WebSocket. Interaction might use higher level messaging patterns like RPC and PubSub.

A design approach of such an app could Model-View-Presenter, with View and Presenter in client side frontend, and model in backend.